# Reason why folder associated with saved webpage gets deleted when we delete saved page

Tags: windows, directory, html

I have saved a complete webpage and there is also one folder saved with resources but when I delete webpage or move saved webpage to other directory then the folder associated with it also gets deleted or moved. So what is the code written behind it. Because I want to do same with my webpage and folder.

Thanks in advance for you kind help.

Comment: This behaviour is on Windows, is not it?

Comment: Yes its in window but the reason behind it? Is there any programming trick which does this?

Answer (score 5):

This "association" between the HTML file and its resources folder is a behaviour implemented by the **Windows** operating system.

It has nothing to due with a webpage in particular, with its HTML, JavaScript, or even with a particular browser.

> Windows 2000 provides a simple way to connect a primary HTML file to its group of associated files. If Connected Files is enabled, when you perform any of the commands [Copy, Cut, Paste, Move, Delete, Send To] on a file or folder of associated files, the same command is performed on all connected files.

Even though the official page mentions "Windows 2000", the same behaviour is implemented in Windows XP and many (if not all) later versions of Windows.

See these pages:

- [Removing file / folder link after using “Save As…” then “Web Page, complete”](https://superuser.com/questions/103280/removing-file-folder-link-after-using-save-as-then-web-page-complete)
- [Operations on an HTML file or folder apply to similarly named folder or HTML file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/252721) (from Microsoft support)